# Gazebo command doesn't open Gazebo

Tags: gazebo, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I've been trying to run [hector_quadrotor](http://wiki.ros.org/hector_quadrotor) packages for a research. For this, I have to launch gazebo simulator. I have installed ROS Kinetic on a 64bit Ubuntu 16.04 LTS machine.

When I try to run;

```
$ roslaunch hector_quadrotor_demo indoor_slam_gazebo.launch
```

I get RViz open correctly. (I couldn't upload a screenshot). It only shows the image part to the left in this similar [image](https://www.packtpub.com/sites/default/files/Article-Images/B04506_image006.jpg). I don't get gazebo open to show me the 3D view of the environment.

So I checked the console log and it shows the following error message.

```
[gazebo_gui-3] process has died [pid 21110, exit code 132, cmd /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/gazebo_ros/gzclient __name:=gazebo_gui __log:=/home/knight/.ros/log/764ebc9e-aa64-11e8-b5f5-6045cb73915a/gazebo_gui-3.log].
log file: /home/knight/.ros/log/764ebc9e-aa64-11e8-b5f5-6045cb73915a/gazebo_gui-3*.log
```

I tried to find such a log file and surprisingly there is none in that folder. I Googled this error message and tried many methods as reinstalling gazebo version 9 and then again version 7 but still it's not opening gazebo.

I tried `gazebo` command on the console itself and it just stays for a few seconds and then I get console prompt again. So I tried verbose;

```
gazebo --verbose
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 7.14.0
Copyright (C) 2012 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

[Msg] Waiting for master.
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 7.14.0
Copyright (C) 2012 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

[Msg] Waiting for master.
[Msg] Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345
[Msg] Publicized address: 192.168.1.102
[Msg] Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345
[Msg] Publicized address: 192.168.1.102
```

After this set of messages I get the console prompt (`knight@AID:~$`) again.

When I quit RViz window, it closes with the following message.

```
 [gazebo-2] killing on exit
```

I wonder what could be the possible reason/s for this failure. Help is much appreciated. Thanks a lot!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/301772/gazebo-command-doesn%27t-open-gazebo/) by [Padmal](https://answers.ros.org/users/37219/padmal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-08-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey there,

I kind of faced a similar situation earlier but was able to fix it with a slight change without any installation/uninstallation.

You might have figured this out already but I'll put the fix here as it might be helpful for others.

The problem is the gzclient's `setup_path` variable.

Edit the `/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/gazebo_ros/gzclient` file by replacing this line:

```
setup_path=$(pkg-config --variable=prefix gazebo)/share/gazebo/
```

with this line:

```
setup_path=/usr/share/gazebo/
```

Then everything worked well for me.

---

Originally posted by [robowarrior](https://answers.ros.org/users/38479/robowarrior/) with karma: 46 on 2018-11-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nullspace](https://answers.ros.org/users/57539/nullspace/) on 2020-09-01**:
could not understand,what you are asking to replace please explain elaborately

**Comment by [nullspace](https://answers.ros.org/users/57539/nullspace/) on 2020-09-01**:
please any one help me to sort this error out

**Comment by [nullspace](https://answers.ros.org/users/57539/nullspace/) on 2020-09-02**:
how will replace the line it is asking administrator problem and could not do in xfce4 also

**Comment by [jungx148](https://answers.ros.org/users/50882/jungx148/) on 2020-09-08**:
The suggested method works perfectly.

setup_path=/usr/share/gazebo/

**Comment by [HyperX360](https://answers.ros.org/users/60359/hyperx360/) on 2020-10-02**:
@null change the file permission first using chmod then replace that line.. worked fine for me.

**Comment by [Shivam](https://answers.ros.org/users/84595/shivam/) on 2021-09-26**:
I was not able to edit that file. My computer doesnt let me edit that file. What should I do?